# User Data (object) Isolation on Instant Messaging

Tags: authorization, instant-messaging, ceph, object-storage, minio

Consider that I want to write an instant messaging application that user can send and receive files privately. I know, it's a good idea to store objects like images in `Object Stores` like `Ceph` or `Minio`, But how can I restrict access to files to the relevant users? Do I need check permission of any request to any file? If yes how can I integrate this authorization to `Minio` or `Ceph`. (`Minio` is preferred.)

Answer (score 1):

One Minio setup comes with a single access/secret key. The multi-user or other permission has to be done from you application environment.

We have documented few scenario on [Multi-tenancy for applications](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/cookbook/blob/68b6dab51f557ed437449104970abcf3bacf4b7b/docs/multi-tenancy-in-minio.md) guide. Also most of our community hangs on [slack](https://slack.minio.io/) channel, feel free to join us.

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)